# Selenium Manager Setup Issues

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seleniummanager

My Chrome browser got updated to 115.0+ today and my RPAs are no longer working. I've read that past Chrome version 115 I need to start using Selenium Manager. I just upgraded to Selenium 4.10 and tried to implement the solution using this logic:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options  import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

But it's telling me that WebDriver is not defined. At this point I'm not sure what I need to install...any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have typos. Try this for Python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing errors for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

---

There's also the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python selenium framework, which already has a fix for the Chrome 115 issue in the latest version: (After `pip install seleniumbase`, run the following with `python`):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Changing to this method is giving me the following error:

Exception has occurred:SessionNotCreatedException
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports chrome version 110
Current browser version is 115.0.5790.99 with binary path c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Applicatio\chrome.exe

Comment: You'll need `selenium` `4.10.0` (or newer). Which version are you running?

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.10.0 earlier this morning. Just to make sure I did it right, from my Terminal Window inside of Visual Code I typed the following command: pip install selenium==4.10.0

Comment: OK just verified that I'm on 4.10.0.  And thanks for your help.  I agree, it's like it's still looking for chromedriver for some reason

Comment: I edited my solution to include a `seleniumbase` solution. It's a Python selenium framework that already has a fix to the Chrome 115 issue.